# How to properly set the indentation?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/SetTextMargins.html) I can set the indentation by using setFirstLineHeadIndent and setHeadIndent.

However, looking at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableParagraphStyle) I don't see those functions referenced. Instead I see an attributes of such names.

I'm currently using following code:

```
double mm2pts = (double) 72 / 25.4;
paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setHeadIndent: 100 * mm2pts / 10.0];
[paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent: 100 * mm2pts / 10.0];
[m_textView setDefaultParagraphStyle:paragraphStyle];
```

I'm testing on OSX 10.8 with my program compiled for the 10.7 minimum.

My question is: will my code compile/run on latest OSX with latest OSX SDK?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

It looks like the code above does not work, while the following code does:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, end-start);
NSTextStorage* storage = [m_textView textStorage];
double mm2pts = (double) 72 / 25.4;
paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent: 100 * mm2pts / 10.0];
[paragraphStyle setHeadIndent: 100 * mm2pts / 10.0];
[storage addAttribute: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: paragraphStyle range: range];
[paragraphStyle release];
```

the idea is to use former for the whole control while the latter for the selected range. Does this mean I should apply the first piece of code to the range of (0, size_of_text)?

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see `firstLineHeadIndent` and `headIndent` listed as properties on `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, just as expected.  Since they are not read-only properties, they can be set as well as read, and thus corresponding methods starting with "set" exist, following the language specification for properties.  So the answer to your question would appear to be "yes".  More to the point, though, it sounds like you need to read up on how properties work in Objective-C.

Comment: Those function are part of the public API and, therefore, needs to be documented. It just confuses people - should I just set the attribute directly or use an "undocumented" function?

Comment: Also please see the edit I pushed. This what made this question in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: The properties are documented, and the fact that the property exists means that the getter and setter methods exist and are also documented.  That is how Apple does their documentation now.  No point in debating it, better just to get used to it.  As for your edit, I apologize but I don't understand what question you are now asking.  Since your original question has been answered, you probably ought to approve this answer and then ask a new question.

Comment: "That is how Apple does their documentation _now_." Since when? Also does this mean that by definition if the doc says "attribute", it has setter and getter. How do they identify "read-only" attributes? Sorry for so many questions - but the should've document setter and getter rather than attribute.

Comment: NSParagraphStyle is *immutable* and therefore every attribute listed for it is read-only. NSMutableParagraphStyle is *mutable*, every attribute listed or IT is read-write. See **@property(readonly, nonatomic) CGFloat headIndent** in the first object, and **@property(nonatomic) CGFloat headIndent** in the second object. This first is clearly annotated *readonly* and the second does not -- therefore it is read-write. The property documentation is perfectly clear.

Comment: <OPINION>I almost never use setter and getter methods anymore. With properties I use dot notation to directly read properties and to set mutable properties. I find it makes for much more readable code. </OPINION>

Comment: @bhaller, I did create a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117771/left-indentation-of-the-nstextview. Trouble is when I call it with start = -1 and end = -1 the control does not get updated. Could you take a look? It just as if I'm missing a refresh or something to that nature.

Comment: "Since when?"  Since Objective-C 2.0, I guess.  Since they added properties.