# Left indentation of the NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, indentation, nstextview

I wrote the following code:

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle;
 double indent = 100 * mm2pt / 10.0;
 if ( !m_textView )
     return;

 if ( start == -1 && end == -1 )
 {
     if( style.HasLeftIndent() )
     {
         paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
         [paragraphStyle setHeadIndent: indent];
         [paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent: indent];
         [m_textView setDefaultParagraphStyle:paragraphStyle];
         [paragraphStyle release];
     }
 }
 else // Set the attributes just for this range.
 {
     NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, end-start);

     NSTextStorage* storage = [m_textView textStorage];
     if( style.HasLeftIndent() )
     {
         paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
         [paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent: indent];
         [paragraphStyle setHeadIndent: indent];
         [storage addAttribute: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: paragraphStyle range: range];
         [paragraphStyle release];
     }
 }
```

The idea is that if the start and end both are equal to -1, left indent should be applied to the whole text view whether there is a text already or not. And the else condition should be applied if I have a selection.

Unfortunately the code inside the if does not work, but the else condition works and I can see the text being indented for the selection.

What am I doing wrong? Because even if the control is empty (no text) and the left indent is applied the text I put in (programmatically or by typing) should have left indentation. But trying to call this code with start = -1 and end = -1 with already existing text does not change the appearance.

Thank you.

Comment: Lots of ambiguity here.  Where is `style` defined, and how exactly is it defined?  What is `HasLeftIndent()` returning?  Why are you using `addAttribute:` in the second block, but `setDefaultParagraphStyle:` in the first block?  It's not at all clear to me that `setDefaultParagraphStyle:` is what you want.  Anyway, this seems like a problem that is just begging for the debugger, not for SO.  Do some detective work and you'll figure it out.

Comment: @bhaller, if not setDefaultParagraphStyle:, than what? I want the left indentation to become in effect on both when I have nothing in the text control or when I have some text, but no selection. It is made by the default attribute, right? Also, since I want it to work on the empty control there is no range, so no use on anything else. lldb does not show anything - just passes thru without any issues. Any idea? Or you are saying that this should work?

Comment: OK, if you want it to affect new typing, perhaps `setDefaultParagraphStyle:` is appropriate, but it seems to me that it won't affect existing text; it sets only the *default* paragraph style.  Why don't you also set it on the existing text, using `addAttribute:...`?